# Create two dynamic test in each loop

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, gradle, testing

I'm trying to create dynamic tests, where each loop is creating two separate tests.
Right now I have the below code, which is creating exactly 7 tests as appears in the ArrayList. Since the name of the test is defined in `.map((testName->` part, only one test is created each loop. Is there a way to separate those two (the first and second assert)? I'm struggling a bit with this type of syntax since I'm new to Java and can't figure it out.

```
@TestFactory
    Stream<DynamicTest> AllPythonTests() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ArrayList<String> inputStream = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList("test_parsing", "test_get_all_targets","test_handle_port", "test_handle_prefix",
                        "test_read_conf", "test_choose_all_targets_from_conf", "test_get_output"));
        return inputStream.stream().map((testName) -> {
            return DynamicTest.dynamicTest("testing: " + testName, () -> {
                String testOutput = getOutput(testName,"");
                org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(testOutput, containsString("OK"));
                String testOutputAsync = getOutput(testName + "_async","_async");
                org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(testOutputAsync, containsString("OK"));

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your list of test names twice; once for each test. (1: testOutput, 2: testOutputAsync).

I mention this as a simple approach. As you're trying to create two things inside the body of the loop. Other solutions could involve using flatMap, but will be more complicated and probably not worth it for code that appears be for test purposes anyway.